# Angular2 Firebase Promises

Tags: angular, firebase, observable, angularfire2

I am playing with Promises in Angular/Firebase. Once I login successfully, I make a call to firebase with the logged in user's `uid`. I use it to lookup the user's "controller name" that is assigned to them in Firebase. This is working to return the controller name in the `snap.val()` But I can't figure out how to get the controller name output to be available elsewhere in my other components.  Should Here's my auth.service.ts code and the corresponding console output to show it's working to pull the `snap.val()`now how can I parse it to get the `controller`value and make it observable? throughout my program?

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ProgramService } from '../views/shared/program.service';


@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  public user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  public userDetails: firebase.User = null;
  public LOGGEDIN: boolean = null;
  private ownersRef: any;

  constructor(private _firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router, private programService: ProgramService) {

    this.ownersRef = firebase.database().ref().child('owners');

    this.user = _firebaseAuth.authState;

    this.user.subscribe(
      (user) => {
        if (user) {
          this.userDetails = user;
          console.log(this.userDetails);
          this.getController(this.userDetails.uid);
          this.LOGGEDIN = true;
        } else {
          this.userDetails = null;
        }
      }
    );
  }

  getController(id) {
    return this.ownersRef.orderByChild('userId').equalTo(id).once('value').then((snap) => {
      console.log(snap.val());
      console.log('just returned getController snap.val');
      return snap.val();
      });
  }

//more code continues here but not needed...
```

**console log data from auth.service.ts after login**

```
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable 
the production mode.
Brian Beardmore
{-LG_PkzB4VV0AjdgKgnG: {…}}-LG_PkzB4VV0AjdgKgnG: 
controller: "Pellet_Pirate_1"
email: "dbrianbeardmore@gmail.com"
name: "Brian Beardmore"photo: "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-YpMyDa8szOw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAACY/pw-_ei54cjs/photo.jpg"
userId: "IeA2gx1Jq4N3vDVovVXHSbOhlqu2"
just returned getController snap.val
```

I want to store the value of the `controller: ''Pellet_Pirate_1''` and make it available to my app. This value **never** changes while the user is logged in.

I would appreciate any help.

thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use LocalStorage to save the information. In your Auth service, you would want to update your subscribe portion of your authentication to save the information into the app's local storage.

```
this.user.subscribe(
      (user) => {
        if (user) {
          this.userDetails = user;
          console.log(this.userDetails);
          this.getController(this.userDetails.uid);
          this.LOGGEDIN = true;
          // save controller into local storage.
          localStorage.setItem('controller', this.getController(this.userDetails.uid));
        } else {
          this.userDetails = null;
        }
      }
    );
```

Then all you have to do now is every time you load a page in your app, check the local storage, look to see if the controller field is defined, otherwise redirect them to the login page.

This would be the sample constructor for your component page:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
  if(!localStorage.getItem('controller')) {
     this.router.navigate(['/loginpath']);
  }

}
```

The more complicated approach would be to use a BehaviorSubject and monitor changes to the Subject.

Comment: Xavid, this works perfectly!  you sir are my "Ambassador of Quan" !!!  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGti242WELo